# Why aliasing dataclass(frozen=True) fails mypy check?

Tags: python, mypy, python-dataclasses

Is it possible to alias `dataclass(frozen=True)` decorator? I tried this:

```py
import dataclasses

key = dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)

@key
class A:
    a: str

A(a="a")
```

And I get the following mypy error:

```
> mypy alias.py
alias.py:9: error: Unexpected keyword argument "a" for "A"  [call-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: I imagine mypy has a special case for classes annotated with `dataclasses.dataclass`/`dataclass`, and that gets lost if you alias it.

Comment: You are right! I now see it in the docs https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html "Mypy does not yet recognize aliases of dataclasses.dataclass"